# Compound mechanical advantage calculation confusion

Tags: classical-mechanics

TL;DR: I can't figure out what the mechanical advantage (MA) is of the system shown below.  Which, if any, of the calculations shown are correct?

Update: stack exchange won't let me post 4 images so I'm combining them all and showing them at the bottom...  I apologize for the need to scroll to see the images.

Full story: I have recently started to use mechanical advantage, and for the most part it seems really straight forward.  I was following a YouTube video on creating a 12:1 compound mechanical advantage system with rope and pulleys, but after I used the system I realized I hooked a few things up wrong.  I drew the system on paper and searched the internet in an attempt to figure out what the mechanical advantage was, but came up quite short.  I can't find a single diagram with the exact same setup.

So, lacking an exact comparison, I searched on how to calculate mechanical advantage and found references to the T method, a method counting the ropes, and a method of counting the pulleys.  Since counting the ropes and counting the pulleys seems to only apply to simple mechanical advantage, I am trying to use the T method.  Every example I have found using the T method has one additional pulley that I don't have, so I'm not sure how to do it.

Anyways, the actual system is shown in the first diagram below.  If it matters, the anchor point is on the ceiling, and the load is on the floor.

The red circles are pulleys, the black circles are connection points, the blue section is a prusik loop rope grab, and the arrow is the direction of force I apply to raise the load.

Using the T method, I first calculated MA as show in the second diagram, labeled 11:1.

Afterwards, I googled 11:1 systems and haven't been able to find anything at all, so I started to doubt my calculations.  After more searching, I found information indicating that when compound mechanical advantage is used, the two systems are supposed to be multiplied.  So, my system is really a simple 5:1 with a simple 2:1, as indicated in the third diagram, labeled 10:1.

So with that, I set back to googling 10:1 systems, and found tons of examples, but again, none were exactly like mine and most had the 2:1 add-on in the exact opposite direction.  So, I redrew the calculation differently and came up with the final diagram labeled 9:1.

But once again could not find another system labeled as 9:1 that looked like mine, and everything I could find had the final 3:1 in the exact opposite direction again.

So, what is my actual mechanical advantage????

[image: MA Calculations]

Comment: Is this a poor question, or is it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer and tension labels in your second diagram (the first with labels) are correct.  The advantage is 11:1

The diagrams after that are nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found source of your problem (because struggled in it myself).
The pulley system you described isn't used in practice, I believe.
The closest real pulley is f.e.: https://landcruising-slacklines.de/media/image/cc/08/16/Landcruising-Slacklines-Sensei-Pulley-06.jpg
But please note the stopper and hence change of direction of the rope.
The prusic pulls different rope in an opposite direction so an advantage of that pulley is 15:1 as all five ropes have T3 tension.

So to make the long story short: real pulleys use stoppers (to prevent backward rope move) and this slightly changes the formula.

And your calculations are correct I suppose, the above just explains why you can't find the exact example of your schema.

Comment: If you are confused too, why are you answering instead of commenting or still doing research?